# сохранение json в csv, VK API

Tags: python, json, вконтакте, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сохранить JSON  в CSV?
Исходник:

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#работает с цифровыми и буквенными id 
import vk
import auth_vk
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import csv
import json


V = '9.95' # Версия VK API

session = auth_vk.auth_vk_token()
api = vk.API(session, v=V)

def main():

    y = api.groups.getMembers(group_id='rhymes', fields='city') # Id группы
    data = y
    json_str = json.dumps(data)
    resp = json.loads(json_str)
    data_items = str(resp['items'])
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(['items'])
    df.to_csv(r'./out.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```

При попытке сохранить файл таким методом выдаёт ошибку:
`futurewarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить!
````

Comment: Вы "лупите из пушки по воробьям", сформировать из списка словарей csv элементарно можно штатными средствами python, без привлечения "тяжелой артиллерии" в виде pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не ошибка, а *предупреждение*, вам не надо ничего делать, пока не будет версии
*pandas 2.0.0+* и ваша программа в ней уже не будет работать.

(В настоящее время версия *pandas 1.4.2*).

---

Но когда оно мешает вам, вы можете вашу команду

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(['items'])
```

заменить командой

```
df = pd.json_normalize(['items'])
```

или просто

```
df = json_normalize(['items'])
```

(т.е. без `pd.` впереди).

---

*Объяснения:*

1. Метод `json_normalize()` будет в будущих версиях (от версии pandas 2.0.0) устранен, он выл с версией pandas 1.0.0 [перемещен как функция прямо в главный простор имен](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#deprecations):

   > `pandas.json_normalize()` is now exposed in the top-level namespace. Usage of json_normalize as pandas.io.json.json_normalize is now deprecated and it is recommended to use json_normalize as `pandas.json_normalize()` instead (GH27586).

   На русском:

   > `pandas.json_normalize()` теперь выставлен в верхнем просторе имен. Использование json_normalize as pandas.io.json.json_normalize теперь отвержен и вместо него рекомендуется использовать `json_normalize()` (GH27586).

---

2. Почему возможно бес `pd.` впереди?

   Потому что у вас есть команда

   ```
   from pandas import json_normalize
   ```